# PyWebkitGTK loads a website fully vertical into window and will not resize inward

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, pygtk, webkitgtk

When I open a site with the webkit webview, the entire window resizes to fit the page not allowing scrollbars. The window's height exceeds my screen height. Also, when a webview is in the window, I can resize the window outward, but I can't resize it inward. A webview won't show at all in a VBox if I do: `MyVBox.pack_start(MyWebview, True, True, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put the Gtk.WebKitView inside a Gtk.ScrolledWindow. since it implement a Gtk.Scrollable you need not using a Gtk.Viewport. and put the window inside your Gtk.Box